# Why fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file (vc++)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I downloaded http://sites.google.com/site/zigmar/notepad2withluasupport source code, opened it in VS2008 and when compiling I got

> Error 1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file:
>   '.\scintilla\win32\ScintillaWin.cxx': No such file or
>   directory c1xx    Notepad

whereas \scintilla\win32\ScintillaWin.cxx does exist as source code project files.

So why ?

Comment: Please check what you typed... ".\scintilla..." exists, and you said "\scintilla" exists. These are two different paths. ".\scintilla" means "c:\currentfolder\scintilla" while "\scintilla" means "c:\scintilla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the sourcecode from the link you provided, however in the project the file is present, in the zip/directory tree the scintilla directory is empty.

Comment: I believe you need to download the rest from http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDownload.html

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: ah ok thanks I'm newbie :) I supposed I need to download scintilla files myself.

Comment: No problems, it really should make that clear on the original site.